# Matrix lookup modelling variants

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, modeling, linearization, indicator-constraints

As part of a bigger model I have a matrix of variables $x_{ij} \geq 0$ and a "selector" set of variables $y_j \in \{0,1\}, \sum_j y_j = 1$.
From $x_{ij}$ I'd like to get the variables of column $j$, where $y_j = 1$, so it's kind of a matrix lookup: $x_{.j}$ with $j = \sum_k k \space y_k$

I'm interested in efficient modelling variants to achieve this. Probably there is not *the* best variant, as it largely depends on the other parts of the model, so proposals are welcomed.

My approach:

$c_i$: columns of $x_{ij}$ where $y_j = 1$
$$
  \forall i: c_i = \sum_j x_{ij} \space y_j
$$
As $x_{ij} \space y_j$ is not linear, I introduce substitute $z_{ij} \geq 0$ and $M$ as upper bound on $x_{ij}$ with

$$
  0 \leq z_{ij} \leq x_{ij} \\
  x_{ij} - M (1 - y_j) \leq z_{ij} \leq M \space y_j \\
$$
So $c_i = \sum_j z_{ij}$ with the constraints from above. It works, but I wonder if it can be improved. What I don't like (beside Big-M) is that I have to introduce additional variables in the size of $x_{ij}$ plus 3 additional constraints per variable - and in the end I only need $c_i$. The $z_{ij}$ are just "intermediates".

Comment: Are the variables $x_{ij}$ are real-valued, i.e. $x_{ij} \in \mathbb{R}_{+}$?

Comment: Yes, $x_{ij}$ and $z_{ij}$ are real valued, only $y_j$ is binary.

Comment: @Christian, what exactly you mean by the multiplication of these two variables? Is it for activating the variable $x_{i,j}$ when each of the variable $y_{j}$ is being one? If so, do you try to use $\sum_{i} x_{i,j} \leq M y_{j} \quad \forall j \in J$?

Comment: Yes, the multiplication is for activating the "selected" column of $x_{ij}$.
$\sum_i x_{ij} \leq M y_j$ is not a valid constraint, as it would force $x_{ij}$ to $0$ for unselected columns. But $\sum_i z_{ij} \leq |I| M y_j$ would be a valid inequality, but I guess my $z_{ij} \leq M y_j$ is "sharper".

Comment: @Christian, I am not sure to understand what you described. if the model does not allow to have unselected $y_{j}$, you should not worry about the mentioned constraint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not really need the $z$ variables. You can just add the constraints $$x_{ij} - M(1-y_j) \le c_i \le x_{ij} + M(1-y_j)\quad \forall j.$$

Comment: Instead of returning a (linear) expression as the lookup's result, using a result variable with restrictions is a nice idea.
Compared it with my model and it got better. Initially I was afraid it might not be as sharp as my formulation, but my tests do not indicate this.

Comment: Just would like to share some feedback: I have determined the lower and upper bounds of $c_i$ as $c^{lower}_i = \min_j x^{lower}_{ij}$ and $c^{upper}_i = \max_j x^{upper}_{ij}$, the left hand $M = x^{upper}_{ij} - c^{lower}_i$ and right hand $M = c^{upper}_i - x^{lower}_{ij}$. Additionally I added $\sum_j x^{lower}_{ij} y_j \leq c_i \leq \sum_j x^{upper}_{ij} y_j$ which helps improving the relaxation in case of $x_{ij}$ with tight ranges (or constants, when $x^{lower}_{ij} = x^{upper}_{ij}$).

Answer (score 3):

If your modeling API supports indicator constraints, you can impose $$y_j =1 \implies c_i=x_{ij}.$$
@prubin’s answer provides the corresponding big-M formulation of this constraint.